# É correto dizer: É possível que eu vá me casar depois da crise? Ou devo dizer: É possível que eu me case depois da crise?

Tags: modo-subjuntivo

Gostaria de saber se posso usar a construçao do subjuntivo com futuro imediato como no exemplo acima, ou se o correto somente seria o uso do próprio subjuntivo:

- É possível que eu vá viajar para Portugal...

ou

- É possível que eu viaje para Portugal...

Obrigada

Answer (score 1):

Em qualquer língua, você pode dizer a mesma coisa de várias formas sem ferir a gramática, embora em alguns casos possa ocorrer uma diferença semântica muito sutil.

> É possível que eu me case depois da crise.
>
> É possível que eu vá me casar depois da crise.
>
> Uma vez passada a crise, é possível que eu me case.
>
> É possível que, depois da crise, eu me case.
>
> Possivelmente, eu me casarei depois da crise.

Gramaticalmente, todas estão corretas.

Quanto às duas frases da pergunta, aos meus ouvidos a sua segunda opção parece melhor que a primeira, onde "vá me casar..." soa ligeiramente como um cacófato.

Answer (score 1):

O modo subjuntivo é aquele que apresenta o fato, a ação, mas de maneira incerta, imprecisa, duvidosa ou eventual. Este é o modo verbal exigido nas orações que dependem de outros verbos.

Exemplos:
Talvez ele chegue mais tarde.

Então:
É possível que, depois da crise, eu vá me casar.
É possível que eu vá viajar para Portugal.

Answer (score 0):

As duas formas estão corretas.

A forma:

É possível que eu vá viajar para Portugal...

Usa o modo composto do verbo (verbo auxiliar conjugado + verbo principal numa forma nominal).

Algumas pessoas não estudam isso no colégio.